# Django: Is it a correct way to override form field of AuthenticationForm?

Tags: python, django

I find it's convenient to use AuthenticationForm of [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) 
But since the username of our client is a little bit long to remember, and the amount of our client is not much, we want to use select widget in the login page. So I use the following code to achieve it. **It works**.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class SignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

in the views.py:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = SignInForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        login(request, form.get_user())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:signin'))
    return render(request, 'account/sign-in.html', {'form': form})
```

However, I can't find any similar usage in documentation. So I'm not sure whether it's correct to do that.

I don't know whether it's similar to ModelForm:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets

I want to know what happen here. Does the username I declare in SignInForm prevent AuthenticationForm from generating its username like ModelForm? But the AuthenticationForm successfully treat the username I declare just like the username it should have generate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good.

The [source of AuthenticationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L154) defined `username` and `password` field. Your subclass overrided the `username` field as normal.

All the form fields are actually implementations of the Python descriptor protocol. They are only general class members there.